# Making nginx replace a css stylesheet

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm using nginx with module HttpSubsModule to replace a few css stylesheets for another. My regex is

```
subs_filter '<link(.*)href="(.+\.css)([\?.]?[^"]*)(".*)>' '<link  href="new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' irg;
```

It seems valid but subs_filter doesn't work with it. Simpler forms, such as

```
subs_filter (.*)css '<link  href="new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' irg;
```

do work but catch a lot of false results.

How should I write this regex?

EDIT: The following version works on [www.regexe.com](http://www.regexe.com) replacing any link tag with a css file, but still doesn't work on nginx.

```
subs_filter '(<link.*href=")(.+\.css)([\?.]?[^"]*)(".*>)' '$1new.css$3$4' irg;
```

Comment: The docs say that it will not work with proxy compressed response. You can disable the compressed response like this: `proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";`. Does it help?

Comment: I've tried to be sure but no. Note that I can make some basic substitution, just not with the complexity I'd like.

Comment: Try with this regex: `(<link.*?href=")(.+?\.css)([\?.]?[^"]*?)(".*?>)`. I think the reason might be in the regex greediness.

Comment: Nothing happens. So far I got this working: `subs_filter href="(.*)css.*" test ir;` but it is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
subs_filter '(<link.*?href=(.))[^"']+\.css([^"']+\2[^>]*?>)' '$1new.css$3' irg;
```

#### DESCRIPTION

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### DEMO

https://regex101.com/r/aF2aU9/1

Comment: I'm no longer working on this but will give it a shot soon when I have the opportunity.